working ubuntu 24.04 install destroyed after trial of dual-boot with win11
I was having a perfectly working installation of an Ubuntu 24.04 on a Lenovo laptop.
I tried to make it dual-boot with Win11 (same hard-drive, no external hard-drives involved in any part of the below process).
I resized the home partition to have some empty space for Win11 using a live-USB-drive of Ubuntu 24.04.
I then created a flash-USB with Win11 and proceeded to install it on the empty space.
This worked fine, Win11 started up.
When I wanted to restart in order to access the Ubuntu distribution, disaster.
grub>  terminal waiting for a command and on top of it the message: Minimal BASH-like editing is supported. For the first word ....
I tried searching for the internet for what I did wrong.
The youtube tutorial for installing dual-boot (Win alongside an existing Linux install) I was following simply logged-in into its Linux distro. I cannot do it.
What I tried
I tried to change the boot order inside BIOS, to no avail.
I tried to use in a live-session of Ubuntu 24.04 (using an USB-flash-drive with the Ubuntu 24.04 iso) the boot-repair utility, but that produced NO recommended actions. The pastebin I got is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cwfQCXCHNt/
And copied here:
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241023_2114]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile] Phoenix3 from NVIDIA Corporation Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: NRCN15WW(1.15) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0002,0006,2002,2001,2003
Boot0000* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (40-C2-BA-45-61-F6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(40c2ba4561f6,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (40-C2-BA-45-61-F6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(40c2ba4561f6,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ccbef867-5269-4962-b764-8316a27b12a2,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0003* EFI USB Device (VendorCoProductCode)  UsbWwid(ffff,5678,0,9207057C0849452056)/HD(2,GPT,eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874,0xb8b5a0,0x27a0)RC
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ccbef867-5269-4962-b764-8316a27b12a2,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) File(.䥗䑎坏S)
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ccbef867-5269-4962-b764-8316a27b12a2,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 4BA87BBF-AF82-48D5-858E-77C9EF5334FE
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
nvme0n1p2    2203648 1065248767 1063045120 506.9G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p3 1065248768 1065281535      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p4 1065281536 1999087615  933806080 445.3G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p5 1999087616 2000406527    1318912   644M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 7.54 GiB, 8095006720 bytes, 15810560 sectors
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1        64 12105119 12105056  5.8G Microsoft basic data
sda2  12105120 12115263    10144    5M EFI System
sda3  12115264 12115863      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sda4  12115968 15808511  3692544  1.8G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:8095MB:scsi:512:512:gpt:VendorCo ProductCode:;
1:32.8kB:6198MB:6198MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6198MB:6203MB:5194kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6203MB:6203MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6203MB:8094MB:1891MB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KXG80ZNV1T02 LS KIOXIA:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:545GB:544GB:ext4::;
3:545GB:545GB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
4:545GB:1024GB:478GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata, no_automount;
5:1024GB:1024GB:675MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME    FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda     iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                                                    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sda1  iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00               eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba14-9014c007d874 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2  vfat     3C53-CAEB                            eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874 ESP                      Appended2
├─sda3                                                eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba16-9014c007d874                          Gap1
└─sda4  ext4     17871899-7ba7-4a70-95ec-874805d8fbbd 3ff734fd-1ef9-4328-bcc2-160d58e7cde3 writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                       Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                  0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs               30.6K  76% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1              iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

I cannot mount (using $ sudo mount ...) any nvme0* partition listed (in a live Ubuntu 24.04 session) with $ sudo fdisk -l. When I write: $ mkdir -p foo && sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 foo/, I get the following error:
mount: /home/ubuntu/foo: special device /dev/nvme0n1p2 does not exist. 

Inside the Win11 install, I went to see if Fast-Startup is enabled, and it is ENABLED, and I turned it OFF. However, as I installed Win11 AFTER having Ubuntu 24.04 working, I understand this makes no difference whatsoever. Tested in practice, the Ubuntu 24.04 installation still does not load and the $grub> ... command-line appears.
Inside the Win11 install, I opened the Win cmd and wrote:
$ bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi and later,
$ bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi, both produced the output: operation completed successfully, but they create in the (windows?)-grub no Ubuntu entry, but only in the BIOS-grub two Ubuntu entries, both of them showing the grub> ... black-screen-of-death output when accessed ... The (windows?)-grub does show Windows11, but that's it, no Ubuntu at all.
I am lost and I do not know how to proceed. Do you see any way forward?
Thank you very much!
EDIT:
W.r.t. duplicate question: the answers there assume one can mount partitions, I cannot do that -- see above the error message I get.
Also, they suggest using the utility, I did that, and I got no useful commands to type in the live-terminal. So it's very much a different situation.
EDIT WITH NEW INFO:
The output of $ sudo parted -l in a live Ubuntu 24.04 session is:
Model: VendorCo ProductCode (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 8095MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name       Flags
 1      32.8kB  6198MB  6198MB               ISO9660    hidden, msftdata
 2      6198MB  6203MB  5194kB               Appended2  boot, esp
 3      6203MB  6203MB  307kB                Gap1       hidden, msftdata
 4      6203MB  8094MB  1891MB  ext4


Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will
be used.
OK/Cancel?

I type OK and press enter
Model: KXG80ZNV1T02 LS KIOXIA (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  1128MB  1127MB  fat32                                      boot, esp
 2      1128MB  545GB   544GB   ext4
 3      545GB   545GB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres, no_automount
 4      545GB   1024GB  478GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata, no_automount
 5      1024GB  1024GB  675MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag, no_automount

LATER EDIT:
I have now clean-installed Win11 from scratch, deleting all the partitions I previously had. I will then later try to install dual-boot Ubuntu 24.04. So I abandoned trying to save what I had as a working Ubuntu 24.04 installation.
Thus, this question is no longer relevant for me, but if anyone fancies answering it, I leave it as it is.

This question is similar to: How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is different it seems, I cannot mount any partition ? And the boot-helper utility does not provide any suggestions for useful commands, only the pastebin ...

Boot report doesn't show any filesystems on the nvme0n1 device -- not even empty ones.  Did the device somehow get encrypted?

@ubfan1, thanks, might it be possible that the Win11 installation ''encrypted'' the device? What I can think of, with my limited knowledge, is the Win's BitLocker option?

@ubfan1, what I am also thinking of is that during the Win11 installation, I might have chosen a different region than what I chose in the Ubuntu installation (and different to the language(s) chosen). Might that affect the fact that I cannot mount partitions?

@user68186 , thanks, I have installed the Pro version - for sure. If it is what you say, it seems there's nothing to do, and I shall start again, the other way around (Win11 first, then Ubuntu) ? I bought the laptop a little bit of time ago, and had no important data on the ubuntu installation, apart from scientific-software packages (MPI-aware CUDA, AMD-BLIS, FFTW, etc.), which indeed took a lot of time to setup and I wish I didn't do them again

What is the mount command that fails? The fstab shouldn't be relevant unless you just tried mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 or something. Does it also fail if you run this: mkdir -p foo && sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 foo/?

@terdon, thanks. I tried what you say, it fails with: /root/foo: special device in /dev/nvme0n1p2 does not exist. I get the same when doing $ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt. When pressing TAB-TAB-TAB for $ ls /dev/nvme0 I get: nvme0 and nvme0n1, only two entries, even if I can see the nvme0n1p2 when writing $ sudo fdisk -l. Unfortunately, I do not remember what command I was using yesterday and failed with fstab error message.

Please add all this to the question, that is very relevant. Ideally show us the output of sudo parted -l when logged into the live session, as well as the mount command and the error.

@terdon, thanks for the help. I updated the Q with output of sudo parted -l in a live session. I cannot mount anything as in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr9oyWjD6IA or in https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1 because when I TAB-TAB-TAB ls /dev/nvme0 , I get listed: nvme0 and nvme0n1, nothing related to p1, p2

Yes, but we need to see that in the question. I don't think I will be able to answer this, I am trying to get the information for someone who knows more than I do so that they can answer, and if it is lost in the comments, they won't see it. So please show that when you try sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 foo/ you get that error. It looks like you have a corrupted GPT (duh, I realize you know this, it's right in the error) and I suspect that can be fixed, but I don't know how.

@mikewhatever the OP is right: if they can't mount the local partitions, the solutions in the suggested dupe won't help.

@terdon, I see, thanks for trying to help anyways. You being in Science as well, you know that it would take a lot of time to re-compile all the packages again in a fresh clean Ubuntu install, thus my efforts not to lose the Ubuntu installation ...
